# Add Tab using EPPlus with MovetoStart Groups First Two Tabs

Tags: epplus

I use EPPlus (current version) to create a new ExcelPackage using an existing template file that has several other tabs. I add a new tab, which gets added as the last tab, and populate the data. If I perform a MovetoStart function on the worksheet, it successfully moves the worksheet, but groups it with what previously the first tab. While it's pretty easy to ungroup, I'm trying to highly automate a process and a workaround is not what I need. Suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [EPPlus Tabs become grouped using MovetoStart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68285973/epplus-tabs-become-grouped-using-movetostart)