# EPPlus Tabs become grouped using MovetoStart

Tags: epplus

I use EPPlus (current version) to create a new ExcelPackage using an existing template file that has several other tabs. I add a new tab, which gets added as the last tab, and populate the data. If I perform a MovetoStart function on the worksheet, it successfully moves the worksheet, but groups it with what was previously the first tab. While it's pretty easy to ungroup with a right-click, I'm trying to highly automate a process and a workaround is not what I need. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this. I don't know why it occurs, but a workaround that worked for me is to select the tab after you reorder the sheets:

```
var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Summary");
workbook.Worksheets.MoveToStart("Summary");
worksheet.View.SetTabSelected();
```